# python combinators list with constraints without itertools

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, combinatorics

suppose I have a list with following elements [a,b,c,d,e]

how can I generate all possible combinations in such a way that every value can be moved to right, left or at the same position. For example with the above list all possible required combinations are

```
(a, b, c, d, e)
(a, b, c, e, d)
(a, b, d, c, e)
(a, c, b, d, e)
(a, c, b, e, d)
(b, a, c, d, e)
(b, a, c, e, d)
(b, a, d, c, e)
```

One way I can think of is, find all permutations and then filter according to the conditions described above but itertools won't work when the list size is 15 for example. Any idea how can I do this for large list?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the rules are; could you explain that a little more explicitly? It seems like you'd be best using itertools on the set of *moves* (back, stay, forward) then applying each one to the list, but are some of those going to be invalid? Working through the 15! permutations and filtering for the 0.0005% that match is definitely not the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you want:

```
def swap_permute(vals):
    if len(vals) < 2:
        return [vals[:]]

    r1 = swap_permute(vals[1:])
    s1 = [vals[:1] + x for x in r1]

    r2 = swap_permute(vals[2:])
    s2 = [vals[1::-1] + x for x in r2]

    return s1 + s2
```

When invoked with:

```
swap_permute(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"])
```

The result is:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e'],
 ['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e'],
 ['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd'],
 ['b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd'],
 ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'e']]
```

This matches the output you posted, and in fact the order matches as well.

The solution is based on the observation that, when `vals` has at least 2 elements, the solutions can be divided into two cases:

1. Those where the first element is in its original position
2. Those where the first two elements are swapped

Comment: I just tweaked it to use a more concise syntax in the assignment to `s2`.  No functional difference.

Comment: I also combined the degenerate cases.  Again, no functional difference.

Answer (score 0):

> every value can be moved to right, left or at the same position

In your example this excludes the first item (which can only be moved to the right) and last (only to the left). Naively, therefore, the valid moves for each of your five items looks like:

```
>>> moves = [(0, 1)] + [(-1, 0, 1)] * 3 + [(-1, 0)]
>>> moves
[(0, 1), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 0)]
```

Where `-1` is move left, `0` is keep at same position and `1` is move right. Once you have this, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all combinations of those moves.

However, you claim 8 outputs for 5 items, and I get:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> all_moves = list(product(*moves))
>>> len(all_moves)
108
```

so it looks like there are some sets of moves that entail duplicates (which is logical - for example `(0, -1, 0, 0, 0)` looks just like `(1, 0, 0, 0, 0)`) and some that maybe can't actually be applied (how would you resolve `(0, -1, -1, -1, -1)`?)

```
>>> all_moves[:5]
[(0, -1, -1, -1, -1), (0, -1, -1, -1, 0), (0, -1, -1, 0, -1), (0, -1, -1, 0, 0), (0, -1, -1, 1, -1)]
```

Therefore your next step is to work out how to apply each tuple of moves to your starting list - for this, you will have to know how conflicts will be resolved (if the first item is moved forwards and the third item is moved backwards, for example, with `(1, 0, -1, 0, 0)`, what is the result?) This may reveal a way you could simplify the problem further.